# Can I say that I am not comfotable doing something asked by my manager?

Tags: communication, manager

I started my job a year ago and finished my first project recently. I am not a native English speaker, and I am always scared of public speaking.
But my manager asked me to make a presentation in a conference.There will be hundreds of audience, which makes me so scard. I am really not comfortable doing it and I am so anxious. (Even though when I think of it, my heart beats so fast.) Is it okay to talk to my manager that I am not comfortable doing it because I am not confident enough and still lack of experience?

Would my manager be mad to me? When he mentioned me the presentation for the first time, I didn't think it was a big deal. But as the time approach, I got more anxious and had a hard time focus on work.

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Better: ask your manager to organise presentation coaching for you.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Can you specify a reason ?

Answer (score 7):

It is obviously okay to talk to your manager and discuss your anxiousness but please take my advice and do not drop out on this presentation opportunity.  This will always haunt you and you will always be scared about it.

You can talk to your manager and clearly tell why you are scared and what would you like to make this experience easier on you. May be they can help in giving you some demo opportunities in front of smaller audience first. Or you can yourself ask your colleagues to sit in a presentation with you for practice.

It is okay if your English is not perfect during the presentation as long as you have a great content. I have seen some excellent presentations in English by people who could barely speak the language.

It is also okay to be little nervous but it is only experiences like this will make you comfortable for your next presentation.

Comment: Even for experienced presenters, a run through with an audience can be helpful for checking timing.

Comment: If you're worried about this particular presentation, maybe you could practice by doing the presentation in front of friends or colleagues, i.e. a smaller group of people you know. Apart from giving you an opportunity to practice in a safe environment, you can also get valuable feedback that way.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you run from a fear it gets bigger, every time you face a fear it gets smaller.

There are groups like https://www.toastmasters.org/ that can help you.

> But as the time approach

How close is the presentation?  If you have waited until the last minute you cannot cancel, it could look really bad.  Just suck it up and do it - it won't go as bad as you fear it will.